# How to make an animation for galaxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, canvas

I wanna make an animation for earth. The aim is to have an presentation of earth in space which should round. JS, Canvas, html, css, jquery. [Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klTKp.png)

Can you give some advice? 
[An example of task](http://thematicmapping.org/playground/webgl/earth/)

Comment: Take look at threejs, should be enough to get you started https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: Check [this](http://codepen.io/chinchang/pen/xCkus) out

Comment: Also try not to ask such broad questions and do a little research first. You get much more useful help that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would check out [this](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/) tutorial.

You write in the title of your question that you want to make an animation - would that be an animation of the solar system, just Earth, Earth and the Moon or what do you have in mind? If you want to simulate the motion of Earth around the Sun, or that of the Moon around Earth or why not the full Earth, Moon and Sun system I would check out the following algorithm that [I have written for simulating gravity](https://github.com/mrhuffman/Attraction). If you check out the example, you should get an idea of how to setup the animation.